# To remove the special character from the column using recursive CTE method

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have a table like this :

```
     |----------------------------|
     |  CardCorporateName         |
     |----------------------------|
     | ~$%/*dfgdggf/*(            |
     |---------------------       |
     | ^^&@~`58964sdhfdk-+*/-=-0  |
     |----------------------------|
```

I need to remove the special character from the column  **CardCorporateName** and my Output should be like this :

```
   |----------------------------|
   |  CardCorporateName         |
   |----------------------------|
   | dfgdggf                    |
   |----------------------------|
   | 58964sdhfdk                |
   |----------------------------|
```

**Is there any method to remove the special character from the column using recursive CTE method?**

Comment: Are special characters anything that's not alphanumeric; or are there any other safe chars?

Comment: @JohnLBevan it should not be alphanumeric..thats all .(need to avoid characters that are not alphanumeric)

Comment: @DeadCat if you only want alpha numeric please see linked post

Comment: @WhatsThePoint but its using via function..is there any method using recursive CTE method? (question edited)

Comment: @DeadCat why are you favouring a recursive CTE over a function?

Comment: using a function its time consuming..using CTE would be better as my table has huge load of data.

Comment: a recursive CTE would take longer than a function?

Comment: it wont..i guess

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('~$%/*dfgdggf/*(', '~$%/*', ''),'/*(','')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('^^&@~`58964sdhfdk-+*/-=-0','^^&@~`',''),'-+*/-=-0','')
```

Comment: please explain your code